# CNAME host is not reaching the app

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, cname-record

This should be a simple issue, but I can't get it to work... Basically I have a customer that sets their domain `test.customer.com` to point via CNAME to `customer.product.com`.

I have nginx rule `listen 80 default_server;` and `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to forward the host to Node.js server behind nginx.

However, when I go to `test.customer.com` I can see in the app that the host is set to `product.com`. So basically I cannot see in code which Host the request is coming from...

How is this possible and why is it not set to `customer.product.com` (which is what I need)?
What am I missing?

**Edit:** this is my nginx config to catch that request:

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;

            location / {

                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

            }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have vhosts setup in nginx for each site?

Comment: I edited the main question to show nginx config -- that's all I have. It's a "custom domain" setting that customers set on our product's dashboard, so I need to know the original host in order to see what customer it is.

Comment: Look in the `Host` header.  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Could you elaborate? The host in the request is currently set to `product.com` instead of `test.customer.com`... That's what I'm trying to figure out how to fix.

Comment: Then it sounds like nginx is mangling the header, but I don't know why.

Comment: Explained in another comment, thanks for debugging with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain whatever is at http://127.0.0.1:3000 isn't perhaps performing a redirect which lands you on `product.com`?

Comment: That's what I also thought initially, so I tried to do `req.get('host');` and it keeps printing my domain (instead of the customer's). Then I also tried to print only requests that come from my IP when I navigate to customer's subdomain, and every host I get is that of my domain again... Not sure what else to check...

Comment: Omfg, tried a wget request and it worked. Asked another colleague across the country to visit the URL and it works. So, looks like it might not be working on my computer only. I'm guessing it's cached somewhere on my end, but I still don't exactly know why because I flushed my DNS a few times and changed IP addresses twice. Looks like a combination of me being a dumbass and me still not knowing what's cached on my laptop. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I'm not sure "accepting" my answer was right here, as it looks like it turns out I was not correct. Glad you found solution though!